# Store different types in a collection in C#

Tags: c#

My basic concept is to store different classes in a collection and retrieve the item based on an interface type.

So the explanation would be better:

```
var list = new List<object>();

list.Add(new Dog());

list.Add(new Rose());

//Retrieve the stored value casting as IAnimal which has Ianimal interface...
list.Get<IAnimal>(); 

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
}

public class Rose : IPlant
{
}
```

Is it possible somehow, or is there any better design for it?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you actually want a `Dictionary<Type, object>`? `dictionary[typeof(IAnimal)] = new Dog()`

Comment: Usually you would use interfaces for such kind of tasks. However in your example the `Dog` and the `Rose` have almost nothing in common so maybe it's better to just keep two collections for each. After all C# is strongly typed language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all items that are `IAnimal` you can use `OfType<T>()` extension method.

```
var animals = list.OfType<IAnimal>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to make one more Interface for your storage List. Its more beautiful encapsulation then.

```
var list = new List<IStoredObject>();

list.Add(new Dog());

list.Add(new Rose());

//Retrieve the stored value casting as IAnimal which has Ianimal interface...
list.Get<IAnimal>(); 

public class Dog : IAnimal, IStoredObject
{
}

public class Rose : IPlant, IStoredObject
{
}
```

Furthermore i guess with @Fedor Hajdu